# Sorting lists in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Could someone please explain how I could sort a list in dictionary? For example:

```
B = {'Mary': [(850, 1000), (9, 10), (1000, 3000), (250, 550)], 'john': [(500, 1000), (800,3000), (20, 100), (5, 36)]}
```

Using the 'sorted' function, how do I sort it in ascending order based on the first value in the list? Likewise, how do I sort it in ascending order based on the second value in the list?

Many thanks

Comment: you mean the first value in the tuple?

Comment: this seems like something they should probably have covered in whatever class this is from ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would iterate through your items, then in-place `sort` based on the first element of each `tuple`.

```
B = {
      'Mary': [(850, 1000), (9, 10), (1000, 3000), (250, 550)],
      'john': [(500, 1000), (800,3000), (20, 100), (5, 36)],
    }

for item in B:
    B[item].sort(key = lambda i: i[0])
```

Output

```
{
  'john': [(5, 36), (20, 100), (500, 1000), (800, 3000)],
  'Mary': [(9, 10), (250, 550), (850, 1000), (1000, 3000)]
}
```

Comment: I liked the brevity of the list comprehension, but this is much more Pythonic.

Comment: Note that iterating over a dictionary in Python 2.7 will automatically iterate over the keys. Thus, `B.keys()` could just be `B`. (source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-for-loops-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use its key argument. Key is a function which takes the element of the iterable as an agrument and returns the value on which sorting is based:

```
for e in B:
    B[e] = sorted(B[e], key=lambda x: x[Element_ID])
```

Element ID is the index of the element on which you want to base your sort. So it will be 1 if you want to sort according to the second element and 0 if you want to sort according to the first element.

EDIT:

Also it would be faster to use list's sort method instead of sorted:

```
for e in B:
    B[e].sort(B[e], key=lambda x: x[Element_ID])
```

Comment: `B[e].sort(key=lambda x: x[Element ID])` would be more efficient because it does not need to construct a new list.

Comment: The question asks, "... Based on the first value in the list." [Element ID] probably should be [0].

Comment: @iCodez He wanted to use sorted but anyway thank you I will add it.

Comment: @user3302763 - It's the choice of which element of the tuple you want to sort on, e.g. x[0] first element, x[1] second element.

Comment: @Casey Falk 'Likewise, how do I sort it in ascending order based on the second value in the list?' I think he wants a general method.

Comment: Yup -- and now that you clarified it makes sense. Although, I would combine `Element ID` into a single variable name (perhaps just elementID) since identifiers should never have spaces in them -- even in pseudo-code.